# Keeping two Upstream Git Repos in sync

Tags: git

I have a work Git repository which is only available on the internal network (origin/master).

For this reason I have a private repo (private/master) and have a master branch which has both repos set as remotes.

They have come out of sync as in the image below:

[image]

Note some of the commits are identical (I pushed to private when there was new commits from another user on origin)

How can I fix this so both remotes are in exactly the same state?

*If possible I would like to keep the work repo version history clean (no Merge commits etc).*

---

Running `git remote -v` gives:

```
origin  https://internal-work-host/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://internal-work-host/repo.git (push)
private https://private-external-host/repo.git (fetch)
private https://private-external-host/repo.git (push)
```

Comment: show your " git remote -v " output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've added that into the question, really sorry for the late response!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to push your code to the remote repository.

```
// Switch to local master branch
git checkout master

// Merge the remote branch into your local branch
git pull origin master

// Now push the combination of the 2 to the remote 
git push origin master
```

Now both branch contains the same code